# Regex to match BOTH specific files name Poster.jpg and Poster.png in a list

Tags: regex

I have an app that lets me search files thousands of folders on my pc to identify any number of criteria. I need a RegEx to search for folders that have files named both poster.jpg AND poster.png only OR that will match when there are at least two files that start with poster. There could be other similarly named files that I don’t care about. I only want to match poster.jpg and poster.png. Nothing I have tried thus far has worked.

According to the application help, application is called FolderSizes, it uses ECMA-262 grammar but I looked at the documentation and I’m more confused than when I started. Help please.

I want a match if both of these names are in the list. And no match if only one or the other are found.

Match because both exist in list
poster.jpg and poster.png

No match because only one or the other exist in list
poster.jpg or poster.png

I have tried /^poster.jpg.+poster.png/
and
\bposter.jpg\b.*\bposter.png\b

and some others but am having no luck at all.

Comment: Why can't you `poster.jpg|poster.png` ?

Comment: That return as match if either ONE of those exist. I need to match only if BOTH exist.

Comment: Ah sorry - I misunderstood...

Comment: I think the problem is that you are only looking for the files in one order  So `\bposter\.jpg\b.*\bposter\.png\b|\bposter\.png\b.*\bposter\.jpg\b` or `poster\.jpg.*poster\.png|poster\.png.*poster\.jpg` would work better.

Comment: Well that certainly does the trick in the regex tester. But it does not work in the application for some reason. I am not sure why. I am going to see if they will help with what their program is looking for. Thank you.